# How to make a Vision output display into a UI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-vision

I am relatively new to coding, and I have recently been working on a program that allows a user to scan a crystal, using the iPhones rear camera, and it will identify what kind of crystal it is. I used CreateML to build the model, and Vision to identify the crystal. What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the results into the UI I built. The results are printing to the Xcode console.

Here's a picture of the Storyboard:

[image: Picture of Storyboard and console]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to draw a box around the detected crystal?

You should be getting a `boundingBox` of your crystal that looks something like this:

```
(0.166666666666667, 0.35, 0.66666666666667, 0.3)
```

These are "normalized" coordinates, which means that they are relative to the image that you send to Vision. I explain this more in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054211/14351818)...

| What you are used to | What Vision returns |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

You need to convert these "normalized" coordinates to UIKit coordinates that you can use. To do that, I have this converting function:

```
func getConvertedRect(boundingBox: CGRect, inImage imageSize: CGSize, containedIn containerSize: CGSize) -> CGRect {
    
    let rectOfImage: CGRect
    
    let imageAspect = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
    let containerAspect = containerSize.width / containerSize.height
    
    if imageAspect > containerAspect { /// image extends left and right
        let newImageWidth = containerSize.height * imageAspect /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newX = -(newImageWidth - containerSize.width) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: newX, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: containerSize.height)
        
    } else { /// image extends top and bottom
        let newImageHeight = containerSize.width * (1 / imageAspect) /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newY = -(newImageHeight - containerSize.height) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: newY, width: containerSize.width, height: newImageHeight)
    }
    
    let newOriginBoundingBox = CGRect(
        x: boundingBox.origin.x,
        y: 1 - boundingBox.origin.y - boundingBox.height,
        width: boundingBox.width,
        height: boundingBox.height
    )
    
    var convertedRect = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(newOriginBoundingBox, Int(rectOfImage.width), Int(rectOfImage.height))
    
    /// add the margins
    convertedRect.origin.x += rectOfImage.origin.x
    convertedRect.origin.y += rectOfImage.origin.y
    
    return convertedRect
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let convertedRect = self.getConvertedRect(
    boundingBox: observation.boundingBox,
    inImage: image.size, /// image is the image that you feed into Vision
    containedIn: self.previewView.bounds.size /// the size of your camera feed's preview view
)
self.drawBoundingBox(rect: convertedRect)

/// draw the rectangle
func drawBoundingBox(rect: CGRect) {
    let uiView = UIView(frame: rect)
    previewView.addSubview(uiView)
        
    uiView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    uiView.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```

Result (I'm doing a `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`):

[image]

If you want to "track" the detected object while your phone is moving, check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66032723/14351818) here

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but I added more details in the original post to try and clarify the vague original post. I am trying to make a UI popup when a crystal is scanned to show details on said crystal.

Comment: @bigdogg99juherd got it. Is `showCrystalInfo` not working?

Comment: @bigdogg99juherd so what is happening currently? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I got you. Just added it.

Comment: @bigdogg99juherd so you are calling after `showCrystalInfo` after `print(firstObservation.identifier, firstObservation.confidence)`, right? Your perform segue code seems fine

Comment: Thanks! How can I buy you a beer?

Comment: @NailsonLandim np, happy to help!