# How to properly place SCNNode on top of the QR Code?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, apple-vision

I want to detect QR codes in the vertical plane and place a node on top of the detected QR. For QR detection, I used Vision framework and Arkit to place the nodes as below code. Whenever placing the node, it is not attached to the QR code and placed somewhere else.

[image]

Could someone help to figure out what I have done wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate,ARSessionDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    var qrRequests = [VNRequest]()
    var detectedDataAnchor: ARAnchor?
    var processing = false

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sceneView.delegate = self
        self.sceneView.session.delegate = self
        self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)

        startQrCodeDetection()

    }

    func startQrCodeDetection() {
        let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest(completionHandler: self.requestHandler)
        self.qrRequests = [request]
    }

    public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
                if self.processing {
                  return
                }
                self.processing = true
                let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage,
                                                                options: [:])
                try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.qrRequests)
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }

    func requestHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        if let results = request.results, let result = results.first as? VNBarcodeObservation {
            guard let payload = result.payloadStringValue else {return}
            var rect = result.boundingBox
    
            let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hitTestQrCode(center: center)
                self.processing = false
            }
        } else {
            self.processing = false
        }
    }

    func hitTestQrCode(center: CGPoint) {
        print("Hit Test")
        if let hitTestResults = self.sceneView?.hitTest(center, types: [.featurePoint, .existingPlaneUsingExtent] ),
            let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first {
            if let detectedDataAnchor = self.detectedDataAnchor,
                let node = self.sceneView.node(for: detectedDataAnchor) {
                node.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitTestResult.worldTransform)

            } else {
                self.detectedDataAnchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
                self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: self.detectedDataAnchor!)
            }
        }
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        if self.detectedDataAnchor?.identifier == anchor.identifier {
            let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.02)
            sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
            sphereNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(anchor.transform)
            return sphereNode
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `center` is a super tiny number (it's a percentage in terms of your `capturedImage`'s size). You need to [convert it first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110582/14351818).

Comment: What does placing a node on top of a QR code mean?  What you are saying does not make sense.

Comment: I added this code:

          `//  node.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitTestResult.worldTransform)
                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)`

the sphere in your screen keeps the position, I don´t know if it your solution but works better.